# Speed up NSThread message passing

Tags: iphone, queue, nsthread, frame-rate

I'm running 2d animations at 12fps in separate threads(2 to 5).
Each thread display image at the specified time at specified location by "performSelector:withObject:afterDelay"
It works fine for 1 animation, but once I have two or more threads to run 2+ animations at the same time, animation slows down noticeably.

It turns out that NSThread takes much more time than specified(in afterDelay)

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay
```

when 2+ threads are calling 'performSelector' simultaneously around 12 times per sec per thread.

Wonder if I can configure NSThread to pick up message queued by performSelector faster.
I'm also wondering what is slowing down the message pick-up. maybe thread switching is slow?

Thank you

Below is threadMain code I use.

```
- (void) myThreadMain
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Add your sources or timers to the run loop and do any other setup.                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runloop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    do
    {
        // Start the run loop but return after each source is handled.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        SInt32    result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10, YES);

    }
    while (self.isNeedToExit == false);

    [pool release];

    SYSLOG(LOG_DEBUG, "thread exiting");
}
```

Comment: if this is for the iPhone (as tagged): can you tell me why (specifically) five worker threads is better than one in your case? (more than one can be useful, in some cases)

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that you draw animation frames in several background threads?

Answer (score 0):

Well man, the answer is simple. You don't get the multicore functionality through multithreads. It means that only one processor is working with all of your threads. So when you are loading 1 animations and there is only 1 thread, there are no thread switches. When there are 2 ore more animations processor is switching between them. Which leads to much more time execution. I have the same situation with my graphs with animation.
Imaging you have normally 1 animation which should run in 1 second and the other animation should normally run in 2 seconds, then when you load both of them simultaneously, the result time would be about 3 second for both.